# 2 forms on same page - jquery context

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have 2 identical forms on a page both have an id

I get the id

```
var parentForm = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
alert(parentForm);
```

then try and get the vale of the fields based on the context.

```
first_name = $('input[name=first_name]', parentForm).val();
alert(first_name);
```

This works for #form1 but not #form2

Comment: try `first_name = $('#'+parentForm+' input[name=first_name]').val();`

Comment: remove `.attr("id")` from the first line

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors, that's correct:

```
 var first_name = $('#'+parentForm+' input[name=first_name]').val();
 alert (first_name);
```

Another way:

```
 var first_name = $('input[name=first_name]', '#'+parentForm).val();
 alert (first_name);
```